# How can I make a Worley Noise algorithm faster?

Tags: python

I wrote an algorithm, that produces 2D Worley Noise in python. But it takes several seconds for a resolution with 400x400 Pixels. I tried to subdivide the space like [here](https://thebookofshaders.com/12/), but I am not able to implement it in Python. I also tried a different method to calculate the nearest point, but it did not work faster...
How can I make it work faster?

```
class Point2D:
        def __init__(self, x, y):
            self.p = [x,y]
        
        def x(self):
            return(self.p[0])
        def y(self):
            return(self.p[1])
        def distance(point1, point2):
            import math
            return(math.sqrt((point1.x()-point2.x())**2 + (point1.y()-point2.y())**2))
        def getDistances(origin, li : list):
            distances = []
            for ll in li:
                distances.append(Point2D.distance(origin, Point2D(ll[0], ll[1])))
            return(distances)
        
class WorleyNoise:
      
    def __init__(self, height, width, density):
        
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.density = density
    def auto(self, option):

        self.generatePoints()
        self.calculateNoise(option)
        self.showNoise()
    def generatePoints(self):
        import numpy as np
        self.points = []
        for _ in range(self.density):
            self.points.append([np.random.randint(0, self.width,1)[0], np.random.randint(0, self.height,1)[0]])
    def showPoints(self):
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        plt.scatter([self.points[i][0] for i in range(len(self.points))], [self.points[l][1] for l in range(len(self.points))])
        plt.show()
    def calculateNoise(self, option):
        import time
        self.data = [[0] * self.width for _ in range(self.height)]
        
        for h in range(self.height):
            start = time.time()
            for w in range(self.width):
                self.distances = Point2D.getDistances(Point2D(w, h), self.points) 
                self.distances.sort()
                self.data[h][w] = self.distances[option]
            print(round(h/(self.height)*100), "%", f" {(time.time()-start) * (self.height - h)} Seconds")
        
    def showNoise(self):
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        plt.imshow(self.data, cmap = "gray")
        plt.show()
        
w = WorleyNoise(height = 200, width = 200, density = 40)
w.auto(0)
```

Edit:

**That‘s the fastest solution I have found until now:**

```
def worleynoise(width, height, density):
    from numpy import random, mgrid, dstack, empty
    from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

    points = [[random.randint(0, height), random.randint(0, width)] for _ in range(density)]  # Generates Points(y, x)
   
    coord = dstack(mgrid[0:height, 0:width])  # Makes array with coordinates as values

    tree = cKDTree(points)  # Build Tree
    distances = tree.query(coord, workers=-1)[0]  # Calculate distances (workers=-1: Uses all CPU Cores)
    return distances


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow, show
    import time
    start = time.time()
    w = worleynoise(1000, 1000, 225)
    print(time.time() - start)
    imshow(w)
    show()
```

The difference to brute force becomes more apparent with a higher amount of points.

Comment: I guess you can start by using a [profiler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) to find out "how often and for how long various parts of the program executed". That should give you a hint about where to start focusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That‘s the fastest solution I found until now:

```
def worleynoise(width, height, density):
    from numpy import random, mgrid, dstack, empty
    from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

    points = [[random.randint(0, height), random.randint(0, width)] for _ in range(density)]  # Generates Points(y, x)
   
    coord = dstack(mgrid[0:height, 0:width])  # Makes array with coordinates as values

    tree = cKDTree(points)  # Build Tree
    distances = tree.query(coord, workers=-1)[0]  # Calculate distances (workers=-1: Uses all CPU Cores)
    return distances


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow, show
    import time
    start = time.time()
    w = worleynoise(1000, 1000, 225)
    print(time.time() - start)
    imshow(w)
    show()
```

The difference to brute force becomes more apparent with a higher amount of points.

Answer (score 2):

Looping over width and height is inefficient if you can use numpy to broadcast your operations, here is your modified code where a new `broadcastCalculateNoise` is used with a benchmarking of both old and new methods:

```
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class Point2D:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.p = [x, y]

    def x(self):
        return (self.p[0])

    def y(self):
        return (self.p[1])

    def distance(point1, point2):
        import math
        return (math.sqrt((point1.x() - point2.x()) ** 2 + (point1.y() - point2.y()) ** 2))

    def getDistances(origin, li: list):
        distances = []
        for ll in li:
            distances.append(Point2D.distance(origin, Point2D(ll[0], ll[1])))
        return (distances)


class WorleyNoise:

    def __init__(self, height, width, density, use_broadcast_ops):

        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.density = density
        self.use_broadcast_ops = use_broadcast_ops

    def auto(self, option):

        self.generatePoints()
        start = time.time()
        if self.use_broadcast_ops:
            self.broadcastCalculateNoise(option)
        else:
            self.calculateNoise(option)
        end = time.time()
        print("total time : " + str(end - start) + " seconds")
        self.showNoise()

    def generatePoints(self):
        self.points = []
        for _ in range(self.density):
            self.points.append([np.random.randint(0, self.width, 1)[0], np.random.randint(0, self.height, 1)[0]])

    def showPoints(self):
        plt.scatter([self.points[i][0] for i in range(len(self.points))],
                    [self.points[l][1] for l in range(len(self.points))])
        plt.show()

    def calculateNoise(self, option):
        self.data = [[0] * self.width for _ in range(self.height)]
        for h in range(self.height):
            for w in range(self.width):
                self.distances = Point2D.getDistances(Point2D(w, h), self.points)
                self.distances.sort()
                self.data[h][w] = self.distances[option]

    def broadcastCalculateNoise(self, option):
        # casting points to numpy, it is of shape (nb_point, 2)
        points = np.array(self.points)
        # simple array of x and y coordinates for each coordinate
        xs = np.arange(self.width)
        ys = np.arange(self.height)
        # use the previously computed xs to get point.x - x for each x
        # notice the use of np.newaxis to control the broadcasting of the result to
        # an array of shape (nb_point, width)
        x_dist = np.power(points[:, 0, np.newaxis] - xs, 2)
        # same for ys, giving a (nb_point, height) shaped array
        y_dist = np.power(points[:, 1, np.newaxis] - ys, 2)
        # use the two last array to compute distance : sqrt((p.x - x) ** 2 + (.y - y ) ** 2))
        d = np.sqrt(x_dist[:, :, np.newaxis] + y_dist[:, np.newaxis, :])
        # d is of shape (nb_point, width, height), but we must sort it along the first axis
        distances = np.sort(d, axis=0)
        self.data = distances[option]

    def showNoise(self):
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        plt.imshow(self.data, cmap="gray")
        plt.show()


print("Using old fashioned loops :")
w = WorleyNoise(height=200, width=200, density=40, use_broadcast_ops=False)
w.auto(0)
print("Harnessing numpy power :")
w = WorleyNoise(height=200, width=200, density=40, use_broadcast_ops=True)
w.auto(0)
```

results in :

```
Using old fashioned loops :
total time : 2.945978879928589 seconds
Harnessing numpy power :
total time : 0.03304648399353027 seconds

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer shows off "numpy power", something I'm unfamiliar with. However, this process can be sped up with the power of standard Python instead/as well. Here is what I've been able to come up with, by removing conditional imports, list initializations (comprehensions are used), numpy.random.randint (random.randint seems faster), and a semi-unnecessary class. This isn't beautiful, but it also isn't ugly and it saves a lot of time.

```
import random
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        
class WorleyNoise:     
    def __init__(self, height, width, npoints):       
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.npoints = npoints
    def generatePoints(self):
        self.points = [(random.randint(0, self.width), random.randint(0, self.height)) for x in range(self.npoints)]
    def showPoints(self):
        plt.scatter([self.points[x][0] for x in range(self.npoints)], [self.points[x][1] for x in range(self.npoints)])
        plt.show()
    def calculateNoise(self, option):
        self.data = [[sorted([math.sqrt((p[0]-x)**2 + (p[1]-y)**2) for p in self.points])[option] for x in range(self.width)] for y in range(self.height)]
    def showNoise(self):
        plt.imshow(self.data, cmap = "gray")
        plt.show()
        
w = WorleyNoise(200, 200, 40)
w.generatePoints()
w.calculateNoise(0)
w.showNoise()
```

By my calculations (CPython, Unix, x86_64), the original (minus the time checking, printing, and matplotlib display) takes 6.037s, and the modified version (minus the matplotlib display) takes 2.556 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the above answers, there is another great tool( [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) ) to make python code faster by compiling complete code before executing it. It makes python act as a compiled language rather than as an interpreter.